# Automatically update a column in a table with a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm having a problem with a trigger code (table mutation and more!) and I can't find
what is the problem.

Basically, I have a table SEMESTER(id_semester, semester_name, begin_date, end_date).
On the insertion of a row, I want the semester_name to be updated with a value according
to what's in begin_date. For example, if the begin_date is '2000-01-01', I want the value of
semester_name to be W00 (for winter 2000).

My first try was to write an 'after insert' trigger, which didn't work because of a table mutation error. Here it is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Test
BEFORE INSERT ON Semester
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    sem         CHAR(1);
    year        CHAR(2);
BEGIN
    -- begin_date is either 1, 5 or 9.
    IF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM :new.begin_date) = '1') THEN
        saison := 'W';
    ELSIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM :new.begin_date) = '5') THEN
        saison := 'S';
    ELSE
        saison := 'F';
    END IF;

    year := TO_CHAR(:new.date_debut, 'MM');

    UPDATE      Semester
    SET         semester_name = CONCAT(sem, year)
    WHERE       id_semester = :new.id_semester;
END;
/
```

After, I tried to make a 'before insert' trigger, thinking it would work better but it does not.

Anyone could point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `id_semester` is the primary key, instead of an `UPDATE` statement, you would just want to assign the `:new.semester_name`

```
:new.semester_name := concat( sem, year );
```

Answer (score 0):

The mutanting table error occurs only with "each row" kind of triggers, try to change your after insert trigger for a "statement" type